# Geometric way to construct image of the image of a point bu given homothety

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Let $ABC$ be a right triangle at $A$ and $G$ a point interior to it.

$D$ is the where lines $(AG)$ and $(BC)$ meet.

Let $h$ be the homothety of center $A$, that transforms $G$ to $D$.

I wonder whether there is a geometric way to place $D'$ the image of $D$ by $h$.

Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just similar triangles your way to get the ratio $ \frac{AG}{AD}$ propagated.

As an example:

- Draw another line $\ell$ through A.
- Pick any point $E$ on $\ell$.
- Connect $ED$.
- Draw line parallel to $ED$ passing through $G$, intersecting $\ell$ at $F$.
- Draw $FD$
- Draw line parallel to $FD$ passing through $E$, intersecting $AGD$ at $H$.
- Since $\frac{AD}{AH} = \frac{AF}{AE} = \frac{AG}{AD}$, $H$ is the image of $D$.

Comment: Can i undersrand why my post got two downvotes ?

Answer (score 1):

With compass center at $A$, make circular arc through $G$ down to segment $\overline{AC}$, to produce point $\hat{G}$ so that $|AG| = |A\hat{G}|$. Analogously, produce point $\hat{D}$ on segment $\overline{AC}$ so that $|AD| = |A\hat{D}|$.

Now draw in $\hat{G}D$ and construct parallel through $\hat{D}$. This line will intersect line $\overline{AD}$ at the point $D'$ that you desire. Why? Similar triangles $\triangle A\hat{G}D \sim \triangle A\hat{D}D'.$

Comment: As an aside, this is my solution with $ \ell = AC$, $ E = \hat{D}$. $F = \hat{G}$.

Comment: Can i undersrand why my post got two downvotes ?

Comment: Probably, people downvoted because your question lacks context and motivation and you don't show any of the effort you put into solving it or where you got stuck. Have a look at this post about [How to Ask a Good Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) on math.se.